# Can't generate V8-4.3 node-fibers binaries for Electron

Tags: node.js, meteor, electron, node-fibers

Ok so I have a nicely bundled [Meteor](http://meteor.com/) app that should now be Node runnable. I'm trying to get it to work with [Electron](http://electron.atom.io). I run `npm install` to add my modules and everything works except fibers creates a folder called win32-x64-3.28 and when I run Electron I get an error, Electron demands win32-x64-4.3 fiber binaries. I've tried building it using node-gyp and continually get the same result.
I'm on a 64 bit Windows 7, Node 12.7, npm 2.11.3, Electron 0.30.4, and fibers 1.0.5.

How can I install the correct version of fibers, win32-x64-4.3, to make Electron happy?